# Micro Service with API Gateway Ocelot vs Nginx

Tags: nginx, api-gateway, ocelot

I have a .net core based micro service architecture.
I chose ocelot as api gateway. My frontend application is vue js based and hosted on nginx container. During a discussion today, I learned that nginx can already be used as a gateway.it was suggested that "you should use nginx for a gateway because you already use for serving frontend, nginx could deploying as a gateway too" I searched the internet to compare the two gateways (I know the main purpose of nginx is not a gateway) but couldn't find any information about their pros and cons like performance,scalability availability etc...

Can someone who uses the 2 technologies share information with me about which one I should choose?

Answer (score 10):

Ocelot is **.NET API gateway** but cloud agnostic. It has following features as mentioned in [article here](https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot). It is a free simple Nuget package for simple installations and not too advanced features or performance requirements, but it beautifully does the job always in .net environment, and provides some features also. It is lightweight, fast, scalable and provides routing and authentication also besides all gateway features. On Azure, Azure API management provides these features plus many more advanced gateway features.

NGinx has a open source version and a plus version.

> NGINX is a high‑performance, scalable, secure, and reliable web server
> and a reverse proxy. NGINX enables all the main web acceleration
> techniques for managing HTTP connections and traffic. For many years,
> NGINX capabilities such as load balancing, SSL termination, connection
> and request policing, static content offload, and content caching have
> helped NGINX users to build reliable and fast websites quickly and
> efficiently.

NGINX can also act as a secure application gateway, offering a number of specialized built‑in interfaces to pass traffic from users to applications. So, as you see NGinx is much more than just an API gateway. With a server, you can integrate many other services like traffic distribution, policies, monitoring, alerts, notifications, custom configurations etc. Ocelot may have limited performance or configurability for an enterprise grade application.

Nginx is a different software than Ocelot. [Kong on NGinx is more popular software for API management gateway and is not .NET specific](https://stackshare.io/stackups/kong-vs-ocelot).

**If your company already is using it, and has it already for deployment, you should continue with Nginx.**

[Ocelot vs Kong vs Azure API management vs Nginx](https://medium.com/hypertrends/microservices-api-gateways-ocelot-for-net-core-video-8bbd4ed3be8f)

In normal circumstances, Ocelot may appear better software than Nginx. But Nginx is a full fledged software. Few reasons: a. Your company has a license for Nginx plus already, why use another software for API management. b. Nginx is configurable for high performance, ocelot is not. [If you use thread pool is nginx, performance can be tuned.](https://panlw.github.io/15401080666894.html)   [Ten Nginx performance tuning tips.](https://www.nginx.com/blog/10-tips-for-10x-application-performance/). You can do limited to none such things in Ocelot. It has its [own bunch of open issues](https://github.com/ThreeMammals/Ocelot/issues) for a gateway. NGinx plus users will have training as well as team support already available. Nginx will be one API Gateway for all of Your applications (technology independent). Ocelot is technology dependent. Given the pros and cons, your company might already be having a Nginx plus license and a common API for multiple applications, and that's why they might be pushing for it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I need a technical comparision about performance and other things. I know everything that you say. I need information like that Nginx is 2x faster than Ocelot or Nginx is more scalable. Because we already implement ocelot. Why should  I migrate to Nginx

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use nginx as a gateway. But Apache APISIX is even a better option to use compared to Nginx and Kong. I found this article helpful while searching for a better API Gateway option to use.
https://api7.ai/blog/why-choose-apisix-instead-of-nginx-or-kong/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32671941)

Answer (score -1):

First and foremost Nginx and Ocelot are very different software.
using Nginx will eventually be good for your infra as it can be used as an API gateway and it's open-source, secure, and offers many other benefits.

Using Ocelot will have disadvantages in long run. You'll need to handle one more software extra. Why would one waste time on that? and the developer will need to understand both of them.

I suggest you go with Nginx as it's already implemented and do your work